# Trouble with Intel Haxm when using AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android, intel, haxm

Ok, I've spent a whole day trying to solve a problem with Android Studio AVD.

I've installed Intel HAXM, enabled Intel Virtualization Technology and found out that there was no Hyper_V in my [Window Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT50y.png).

However, when I tried to run my project in Android Studio AVD, I still got the same error:

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I'm really fed up with this, I still got class tomorrow (Android Game Programming), so can someone help me with this?

Comment: HyperV is not required for this. You need a CPU that supports virtualization extensions. Does your CPU support it?

Comment: Yeah, it supports virtualization. I just thought that HyperV might be the cause? I was quite desperate at that time, you see...